# The argument 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, google-chrome, dart

i am trying to navigate from one page to another but when i try to call a particular value (stuff), it shows me this error, even though in this case both the argument type and the parameter type are the same

```
class ProductList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> stuff;
  final Function addProduct;
  final Function updateProduct;


  const ProductList(
    this.stuff, this.addProduct, this.updateProduct, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: Image.asset(stuff[index]['image']),
          title: Text(stuff[index]['title']),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
            onPressed: (){                           
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return ProductCreate(stuff: stuff[index], addProduct: addProduct, updateProduct: updateProduct ,);
                })
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: stuff.length,
    );
  }
}
```

Down below is the productCreate

```
class ProductCreate extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function addProduct;
  final Function updateProduct;
  final List <Map<String, dynamic>> stuff;


  ProductCreate({required this.addProduct, required this.stuff, required this.updateProduct});


  @override
  State<ProductCreate> createState() => _ProductCreateState();
}
```

as said, when i tried calling stuff while navigating to the productCreate, it flags that error. im pretty new to flutter so maybe there is something im missing. help would be really appreciated

Comment: Can you add info about what you send from other page. Is it a data class? If it is , you just need to named as List<Your Data Class> stuff

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure what a you trying to do. But if you only want to pass a single item to `ProductCreate`, then try below code.
Because you only send single item to `ProductCreate` but the parameter at `ProductCreate` set to `list` type.

```
class ProductCreate extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function addProduct;
  final Function updateProduct;
  final <Map<String, dynamic>> stuff;


  ProductCreate({required this.addProduct, required this.stuff, required this.updateProduct});


  @override
  State<ProductCreate> createState() => _ProductCreateState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are sending the single item of stuff in the ProductCreate  class .. so you just send stuff not stuff[index]

```
class ProductList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> stuff;
  final Function addProduct;
  final Function updateProduct;


  const ProductList(
    this.stuff, this.addProduct, this.updateProduct, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: Image.asset(stuff[index]['image']),
          title: Text(stuff[index]['title']),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
            onPressed: (){                           
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return ProductCreate(stuff: stuff, addProduct: addProduct, updateProduct: updateProduct ,);
                })
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: stuff.length,
    );
  }
}
```